# How to use a Info Bubble for Clusters with Google V3 Maps

Tags: javascript, html, google-maps, google-maps-api-3, markerclusterer

I have a Info Bubble in my Cluster Map. Currently I have my markers showing an info bubble when you click or hover over them. I cannot get my clusters to have the same?

How to I show a info bubble over my clusters when you hover or click on a cluster?

[Here is a link to my file](http://www.blakeloizides.co.za/marker/clusters.html)

```
<html>    
<head> 
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://blakeloizides.co.za/marker/js/jquery-1.6.1.min.js"></script>        
<script src="http://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?sensor=false" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://blakeloizides.co.za/marker/js/gmap3.js"></script> 
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://blakeloizides.co.za/marker/js/mcdo.js"></script> 
<style>
  #container{
    position:relative;
    height:700px;
  }
  #googleMap{
    border: 1px dashed #C0C0C0;
    width: 75%;
    height: 700px;
  }

  /* cluster */
  .cluster{
    color: #FFFFFF;
    text-align:center;
    font-family: Verdana;
    font-size:14px;
    font-weight:bold;
    text-shadow: 0 0 2px #000;
    -moz-text-shadow: 0 0 2px #000;
    -webkit-text-shadow: 0 0 2px #000;
  }
  .cluster-1{
    background: url(images/card-cluster.png) no-repeat;
    line-height:64px;
    width: 64px;
    height: 40px;
  }
  .cluster-2{
    background: url(images/house.png) no-repeat;
    line-height:53px;
    width: 60px;
    height: 48px;
  }
  .cluster-3{
    background: url(images/headquarters.png) no-repeat;
    line-height:66px;
    width: 70px;
    height: 56px;
  }

  /* infobulle */
  .infobulle{
    overflow: hidden; 
    cursor: default; 
    clear: both; 
    position: relative; 
    height: 34px; 
    padding: 0pt; 
    background-color: rgb(57, 57, 57);
    border-radius: 4px 4px; 
    -moz-border-radius: 4px 4px;
    -webkit-border-radius: 4px 4px;
    border: 1px solid #2C2C2C;
  }
  .infobulle .bg{
    font-size:1px;
    height:16px;
    border:0px;
    width:100%;
    padding: 0px;
    margin:0px;
    background-color: #5E5E5E;
  }
  .infobulle .text{
    color:#FFFFFF;
    font-family: Verdana;
    font-size:11px;
    font-weight:bold;
    line-height:25px;
    padding:4px 20px;
    text-shadow:0 -1px 0 #000000;
    white-space: nowrap;
    margin-top: -17px;
  }
  .infobulle.drive .text{
    background: url(images/drive.png) no-repeat 2px center;
    padding:4px 20px 4px 36px;
  }
  .arrow{
    position: absolute; 
    left: 45px; 
    height: 0pt; 
    width: 0pt; 
    margin-left: 0pt; 
    border-width: 10px 10px 0pt 0pt; 
    border-color: #2C2C2C transparent transparent; 
    border-style: solid;
  }

</style>

<script type="text/javascript">

  $(function(){

    $("#googleMap").gmap3({
      map:{
        options: {
          center:[46.578498,2.457275],
          zoom: 7,
          mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.TERRAIN
        }
      },
      marker: {
        values: macDoList,
        cluster:{
          radius:100,
          // This style will be used for clusters with more than 0 markers
          0: {
            content: "<div class='cluster cluster-1'>CLUSTER_COUNT</div>",
            width: 53,
            height: 52
          },
          // This style will be used for clusters with more than 20 markers
          20: {
            content: "<div class='cluster cluster-2'>CLUSTER_COUNT</div>",
            width: 56,
            height: 55
          },
          // This style will be used for clusters with more than 50 markers
          50: {
            content: "<div class='cluster cluster-3'>CLUSTER_COUNT</div> + <div>hello</div>",
            width: 66,
            height: 65
          }
        },
        options: {
          icon: new google.maps.MarkerImage("images/card-marker.png")
        },
        events:{
            mouseover: function(marker, event, context){
$(this).gmap3(
              {clear:"overlay"},
              {
              overlay:{
              latLng: marker.getPosition(),
              options:{
              content:  "<div class='infobulle"+(context.data.drive ? " drive" : "")+"'>" +
                  "<div class='bg'></div>" +
                  "<div class='text'>" + context.data.city + " (" + context.data.zip + ")</div>" +
                  "</div>" +
                  "<div class='arrow'></div>",
              offset: {
              x:-46,
              y:-73
              }
              }
              }
              });},

          mousedown: function(marker, event, context){
            $(this).gmap3(
              {clear:"overlay"},
              {
              overlay:{
                latLng: marker.getPosition(),
                options:{
                  content:  "<div class='infobulle"+(context.data.drive ? " drive" : "")+"'>" +
                              "<div class='bg'></div>" +
                              "<div class='text'>" + context.data.city + " (" + context.data.zip + ")</div>" +
                            "</div>" +
                            "<div class='arrow'></div>",
                  offset: {
                    x:-100,
                    y:-73
                  }
                }
              }
            });
          },
          mouseout: function(){
            $(this).gmap3({clear:"overlay"});
          }
        }
      }
    });

  });
</script>  
</head>

<body>
<div id="googleMap"></div>
</body>
</html>
```

I have been trying the following:

```
mouseover: function(marker, event, context){
$(this).gmap3(
              {clear:"overlay"},
              {
              overlay:{
              latLng: marker.getPosition(),
              options:{
              content:  "<div class='infobulle"+(context.data.drive ? " drive" : "")+"'>" +
                  "<div class='bg'></div>" +
                  "<div class='text'>" + context.data.city + " (" + context.data.zip + ")</div>" +
                  "</div>" +
                  "<div class='arrow'></div>",
              offset: {
              x:-46,
              y:-73
              }
              }
              }
              });},
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A cluster is not a marker, it's a group of markers.

The properties of the cluster you may access via the first argument of the callback. 
The first argument consist of two members, main and shadow .

Use the method `getPosition()` of the `main`-member to retrieve the position of the cluster.

The markers for the cluster are stored as an array inside the data.markers-member of the 3rd argument, you may collect some informations from this array to show them inside the infobubble.

example:(add this to the `events`-member of the **cluster**)

```
mouseover: function(cluster, event, context){
              $(this).gmap3(
                  {clear:"overlay"},
                  {
                    overlay:{
                        latLng: cluster.main.getPosition(),
                        options:{
                                  content:  "<div class='infobulle'>" +
                                            "<div class='bg'></div>" +
                                            "<div class='text'>there are " +
                                             context.data.markers.length +
                                            " markers in this cluster</div>" +
                                            "</div><div class='arrow'></div>",
                                  offset: {
                                            x:-46,
                                            y:-73
                                          }
                                }
                            }
                  });
  }
```